# How to set two values in View()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How can set several objects in view?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    var shops = this.context.shops.Select(q => new { q.id, q.name }).ToList();
    var bikes = this.context.bikes.Select(q => new { q.id, q.name }).ToList();
    return View(shops, bikes); // How to set two values in View()?
}
```

And parse in View()

```
@foreach (var r in Model.bikes)
{
    <b>@r.name</b>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create ViewModel

```
   public class shopsAndbikes 
    {
     public List<shop> shops {get;set;}
     public List<bike> bikes {get;set;}

    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {             
       shopsAndbikes vm = new shopsAndbikes ()
       {
        var shops = this.context.shops.Select(q => new { q.id, q.name }).ToList();
        var bikes = this.context.bikes.Select(q => new { q.id, q.name }).ToList();
       }
      return View(vm);    
    }
```

View:

```
@model shopsAndbikes 

@foreach (var r in Model.bikes)
{
    <b>@r.name</b>
}

@foreach (var r in Model.shops)
{
    <b>@r.name</b>
}
```

Comment: `object` does not contain a definition for `shops`

Comment: Make sure you do not forget about modifier Public

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a strong typed view model that contains both shops and bikes. Other option could be creating a Tuple and passing as a model to view. I would go first option.

### Tuple

```
var tuple = new Tuple<shop, bike>(new shop(),new bike());
```

In you view

```
@Model Tuple<shop,bike>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Model-class should contain properties for both shops and bikes. That is if you use a strongly typed view, it looks that way. Otherwise you could add things to the ViewBag for use in the view.